# Two theoretically identical codes not generating the same output

Tags: r

I am trying to run a routine in **R**, involving replicating a random experiment. I encountered errors with the dimension of the output, which led me to discover the following peculiarity:

```
length(replicate(100 - 100*8 / 10, 4))
# 20
length(replicate(100 *(1- 8/ 10), 4))
# 19
```

As a sanity check, I ran the lines of code to make sure that the expressions in the first argument of `replicate` produced the same output.

```
100 - 100*8 / 10
# 20
100 *(1- 8/ 10)
# 20
```

I was wondering if people are experiencing the same issue. *What I really want to know is, why does this happen?*

Note: I am aware of the difference between `rep` and `replicate`, and my routine requires the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not exactly the same

```
(100 *(1- 8/ 10)) == 20
#[1] FALSE

(100 - 100*8 / 10) == 20
#[1] TRUE
```

because

```
20 - (100 *(1- 8/ 10))
#[1] 3.552714e-15
```

and the `n` in `?replicate` is an integer

> n - integer: the number of replications.

Converting that output to `integer` `floor`s to 19

```
as.integer((100 *(1- 8/ 10)))
#[1] 19

floor((100 *(1- 8/ 10)))
#[1] 19
```

---

One option is to wrap with `ceiling`

```
length(replicate(ceiling(100 *(1- 8/ 10)), 4))
#[1] 20
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the fact that [floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), because of finite machine precision.

In your case, this issue presents itself as `1- 8/10` not being the same as `0.2`:

```
identical(    8/10, 0.8 )   # TRUE
identical( 1- 8/10, 0.2 )   # FALSE
```

The root cause is that there is no way to precisely represent 0.8 and 0.2 in binary with a finite number of bits. In the memory, these values are effectively rounded to the nearest 32-bit or 64-bit binary representation. This rounding then cascades through the arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common floating-point arithmetic problem present in many programming languages. Some further reading on the topic can be found here.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems
- https://floating-point-gui.de/